# How is IoT communication different from normal PC cummunication?

Tags: security, networking, iot, communication, aws-iot

These are many articles on internet, researches on the point that their is need to make IoT communication more secure. What are the difference in IoT communication and conventional communication, that there arise need of so much extra research, emergence of new communication protocols etc.. I may be missing some crucial point here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IoT devices are cheap, small and have limited processing power. Therefore, their software typically doesn't contain the security features of desktop operating systems (implementing an SSL protocol is just not possible on many devices, because they don't have enough capacity). Despite that, IoT devices such as smartwatches transmit highly sensitive information, such as the whereabouts of its wearer and things like his night-time activities...

Additionally, many cheap IoT devices come with *one* preinstalled, unchangeable software. Or software that never gets any updates after the product is launched. This makes it easy for hackers to abuse these devices once a security leak is found in the code.